# Applying number format on a column from a specific row number using SpreadsheetGear

Tags: spreadsheetgear

I am using SpreadsheetGear to generate a excel sheet. I want to apply number formatting on a column starting from row number 10.

But when I use below code, it apply formatting for the entire column.

```
worksheet.Cells[10, 2].EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "@";
```

**How can I ensure formatting is applied for the entire column starting from row number 10.**

Answer (score 2):

This could be accomplished any number of ways.  One might be to "subtract" the top 10 rows from the entire column, which could be done using IRange.[Subtract](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.IRange~Subtract.html)().  Example:

```
// First obtain a reference to all of Column C, then "subtract" the first 9 rows from it
IRange range = worksheet.Cells["C:C"].Subtract(worksheet.Cells["C1:C9"]);
// Apply your formatting...
range.NumberFormat = "@";
```

Another would be to use *zero-based indexes* to select the desired range, using the IWorkbookSet.[MaxRows](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.IWorkbookSet~MaxRows.html) property to determine the maximum row (currently 1,048,576, as per Excel’s file format limitations).  Example:

```
IRange range = worksheet.Cells[9, 2, worksheet.WorkbookSet.MaxRows - 1, 2];
```

Lastly, you could hard-code the range using an A1-style reference, knowing that the current file format limitation is 1,048,576 rows.  Example:

```
IRange range = worksheet.Cells["C10:C1048576"];
```